# how loop through all users not assigned to current ticket?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel eloquent and I would like to loop through all users that haven't been assigned to the ticket yet (also worth noting the relationship between my tickets and users is stored in my pivot table), so that the same user cannot be assigned to the same ticket multiple times over. My select statement is clearly wrong but I've yet to figure out how to do it.

TicketController.php

```
public function info($slug){

    //loop through all users
    //$users = \App\User::all();

    //trying to select all users not assigned to the ticket
    $users = User::select('*')->join('tickets','ticket_id','id')- 
    >where('id','!=','ticket_id')->get();

    return view ('admin.admin_info',['tickets' =>$tickets], 
    ['users'=>$users]);
}
```

admin_info.blade.php my foreach loop

```
  @foreach($users as $user)                                    
   <input type="checkbox" name="id" value=" {{$user->id}}">{{$user->name} <br>
  @endforeach
```

User.php model

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','admin',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public function tickets(){
    return$this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class,'ticket_user','id','ticket_id');
}
}
```

Ticket.php model

```
  class Ticket extends Model
 {
//
public function client(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class,'client_id');
}
public function users(){
    return $this- 
    >belongsToMany(User::class,'ticket_user','ticket_id','id');
}

protected $primaryKey = 'ticket_id';
public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this:

```
$ticket = Ticket::findOrFail($id);

$selected_users = $ticket->users()->pluck('users.id')->toArray();

$users = User::whereNotIn('id', $selected_users)->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Please note that if the variable name you want to pass on the blade file is the same on what you have on your controller, you can just use `compact` function like so:

```
return view ('admin.admin_info', compact('tickets', 'users'));
```

Then on your **Blade** file:

Please note that you're missing one ending bracket character.

```
@foreach($users as $user)                                    
   <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}<br/>
@endforeach
```